# Cannot add Socket.io library into Android project

Tags: android, socket.io

I have problem with adding some libraries and confuse strangely . I've search alot but have no success , Thanks .

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your gradle compiling without any errors?

Comment: yess , it builds completely

Comment: Try clean and rebuild project.

Comment: I tried , but no success